# Comparing std::vector or std::set in this case for time complexity - More efficent?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, set

I currently have a function that returns strings. I need to keep a track of these returned strings and if an action is not taken on a returned string then I have to take an action on it.

My first thought is using a vector (i.e) std::vector.

Here is what a mechanism utilizing a vector would look like

1-Check if item exists in a vector using std::find

```
std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item)!=vector.end()
```

2-If item not present do a push_back (Amortized constant)
and perform an action on it else ignore the string

My second thought is using a std::set

1-Check if item exists in set by doing the insert function
if not insert it

```
 if(set.insert(somestring).second)
    {
      //Item inserted in set and it did not exist

    }
```

The time complexity of insert in set is `O(logn)`. The push_back of vector is Amortized constant and if the vector isn't sorted(in this it isn't) std::find will be O(n). Is my assumption correct that for maximum efficiency i should be using a set here ? Is there anything that I might be missing ?

Comment: I'm new, but why not use a hash table, an std::map or an std::unordered_map to check if it exists? You're storing strings anyway.

Comment: "if the vector isn't sorted(in this it isn't) it will be O(logn)" - what will be O(logn)?

Comment: just updated it. I meant `std::find` on `std::vector<std::string>` will O(n)

Comment: @MistyD: No, it will be O(n).

Comment: Yes you are correct. Sorry that was a typo- it will be O(logn) if it was sorted. since its not it will be O(n)

Comment: Lookups on a `vector` are O(n). Lookups on a `set` are O(log n). Lookups on an `unordered_set` are O(1). I think we have a clear winner.

Comment: So i should be using an unordered_set ?. By lookup you mean when I use `insert` and the pair result that I get back or the `find` method.

Comment: I mean `find` or its equivalent.

Comment: Profile first. Is the choice of containers actually measurably affecting your performance, or is your run time being dominated by the extra processing? `vector` has better locality, especially if your strings are short and your standard library uses the small string optimization. `unordered_set` have the best asymptotic complexity on paper if you don't hit the pathological O(N) lookup case, but whether that translates to better performance is a different question.

Comment: If he's wanting a set of strings a Trie might actually be the better data structure.

Comment: @MarkRansom Lookups on an `unordered_set` are highly dependent on the quality of the hash function.  And even with a good hash function: if the data is well distributed, with `std::set`, you will only have to look at the first character or so until the final comparison; with a hash table, you will need to look at them all at least twice.  I did some measurements once (a long time ago), and found that you needed about 100000 strings before hash tables started beating `std::set`.  (Of course, today, locality can also play a role, and sometimes, `std::vector` will be faster than either.)

Comment: @MorphingDragon Yes, but he'd have to write that one.  The other options, he has for free.

Comment: @JamesKanze it appeared the question was about complexity, not overall efficiency. Although looking back it's possible that I misinterpreted it.

Comment: @MarkRansom The question was expressed in terms of complexity.  But in the end, the reason we worry about complexity is performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to work on a foreign exchange pricing system in a bank. Performance was of great interest to us. We used to have long discussions on optimal algorithms... And then one day we measured the performance with a profiling tool.... and we found that the actual algorithms used up 5% of the processing time. The remaining 95% was taken up in converting strings to doubles and doubles to strings when the system received and sent messages to and from the message bus.

Why do I write this? Just to illustrate that in almost all cases, the choice of your container is probably irrelevant. Your program is very unlikely to spend more than a fraction of its time finding items in maps, sets or vectors.

Write the code in the most elegant and maintainable way you can, using easily understood algorithms, and containers that naturally fit the design (sets and maps for things that need to be ordered, vectors for general storage, unordered sets and maps if order isn't important and your data sets are huge). If you need multiple ordered indexes on the same data then probably a vector for storage with sets of iterators/pointers for indexing (like a database).

Then, when it's finished, if your users are screaming at you that it's too slow (they won't - they're more concerned about it working reliably), profile the code and measure for bottlenecks. They will almost always be in the I/O.

If in the incredibly unlikely scenario that your code is spending 90% of its time managing collections of data, then it's time to rethink the algorithm because the design is probably inefficient - or you're writing a protein folding simulator.

If you're sure that the design is optimal, then maybe it's time to reconsider the type of the container.

There are only fundamentally 3 types - you can find the best solution by trial and error in less time than it takes to argue about it.

:-)

Comment: Even in places like video games and real time processing, we tend to get it correct and then pull out all the stops to optimize the shiz out of it.

Comment: ...and I bet you spend more cycles pushing data across the bus to the video card than you do managing your oct-tree right?

Comment: It depends on the architecture. Newer SoCs or APUs don't tend to suffer from that so much as the CPU and GPU share memory. Even then the main "fix" is to make the renderer multithreaded so it can deal with waiting on the GPU.

Comment: "QuickSort vs MergeSort" is probably the best argument for actually profiling your code. Both have the same complexity on paper but behave much differently depending on the computer's resources and the size of the data set.